# emacs 28.0.50 `sh-quoted-exec` has different coloring for `sh` and `bash`

Tags: shell, bash, shell-mode, customize-face

In `Shell-script[bash]` mode, coloring differs for `sh-quoted-exec` in `#!/bin/sh` and `#!/bin/bash`.

If `#!/bin/sh` is the first line: // I prefert this
[image]

If `#!/bin/bash` is the first line:
[image]

Would it be possible to have same coloring in `sh` for `bash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually toggle which features Emacs will apply to your file via `M-x sh-set-shell`: pick `/bin/sh` to get the variant you prefer. You can set this automatically for a file by adding the following code at the end of the file:

```
# Local Variables:
# sh-shell: sh
# End:
```

To illustrate, with this file:

```
#!/bin/bash
alper=$(gdrive list --query "'$id' in parents" --no-header | grep "patch_")

# Local Variables:
# sh-shell: sh
# End:
```

I see this:

[image]

It doesn't change the `#!` directive on the first line, and I get the syntax highlighting of the `sh` style in a `bash` script. This is with Emacs 28.0.50, started with `emacs -Q`.

To enable this automatically for all bash scripts, you can use the following hook:

```lisp
(defun my-set-shell ()
  (sh-set-shell "sh"))

(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook 'my-set-shell)
```

Comment: Inside `$()` when the complete string colored in same its hard to understand. Like strings (`"blabla"`) was in green. Only the `gdrive` on the example colored into maganta and its parementers except `"'$id' in parents"` was white

Comment: I have select `sh` but it changes `#!/usr/bin/bash` into `#!/usr/bin/sh`. I want to keep it as `#!/usr/bin/bash` if possible and apply the sh's theme into `#!/usr/bin/bash`. Please note that I didn't have this issue on emacs 27 or 26

Comment: I can't reproduce this here. I'm using Emacs 28.0.50. I've updated my answer to show you exactly how the buffer appears to me.

Comment: Same here I am using 28.0.50 as well, where there was no issue on versions below 28.0. Can I have this solution without having `Local Variables` written below? I have plenty of `*.sh `file and it will be difficult to make changes on all

Comment: I added a hook that should handle this automatically

Comment: Thanks! Small question command words like `gdrive` or `ls`, `pwd`, `cat` etc. was in different color which was in <28.0 version; would it be also possible to make them in color?